# Database structure for complex organized image posts

Tags: html, database, git, image, database-design

I'm sorry the title is not very clearly, but I'll try to explain as best as I can.

In a website I'm working on we periodically publish content consisting of images presented always in different ways. You can think of the content as posts, or episodes: the main thing is that their structure is always different. Every time I prepare the the `html`, `css` and `scripts` as needed to present the images in a specific arrangement.

Just to give you some practical examples: sometimes it can be a simple slideshow, sometimes can be a slideshow, but some of the slides need to contain 3 different pictures next to each other. Other times it can be something like a photojournal, but maybe there are background pictures alternating.

I'm having trouble managing the image assets through a database or something convenient.

At the moment I'm managing all the images as static assets. I have them on my machine, name them manually and insert them in the html. This system works, but in the long run is not feasible. The git repository will be soon too big and if an image needs to be replaced can't be done automatically.

One obvious improvement would be to have an `images` table a `pages` table and a relation table between the two. This will let me always get the images I need for a specific page, but how can I know the role of an image? Or its position?

I hope I explained the problem, but I can edit to add details. I didn't put any code because the problem is not related to any specific piece of code, hope that's ok.

Comment: Your idea on the `images` and `pages` tables is good, but clearly you cannot model something that 'is always different'. So you're stuck. You can choose to either restrict the many ways in which the image can be presented somewhat, or not to model that part and keep doing it by hand. You can still refer to the images in the database though.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Restricting the arrangements is not an option, because it's actually the main feature of the project and I'm not the one deciding. What I was thinking, was to add a `tag` field or `role` in the relation table to be able to identify the images